Device Admin features such as wipe data or changing password is not authorized after Android 14 update?
After properly adding it as an admin app, other DPM functions work fine (such as dpm.lockNow()).
I can also wipe the data on android 10. The issues occur on android 14,13.
  fun wipeData() {
        var flags = 0
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
            flags = flags.or(DevicePolicyManager.WIPE_SILENTLY)
        if (prefs.isWipeEmbeddedSim && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P)
            flags = flags.or(DevicePolicyManager.WIPE_EUICC)
        dpm?.wipeData(flags) 

    }

Faced with following error.
java.lang.SecurityException : User 0 can not be removed .

In Android 14 the app must now be set up after a factory reset as a device owner/organisation.
The only way I could get all my admin functions to work was run an adb command setting the app as the device administrator
Have to update you manifest with some new permissions as well.
Push the APK to the device using the following ADB command:
adb install "PATH TO YOUR APK"

Set the app as a device owner using the following command:

adb shell dpm set-device-owner com.dataguard.pro/.MyDeviceAdminReceiver
Make sure to replace com.dataguard.pro with your app name.

Since Android 14, wipeData is replaced with wipeDevice.
Read here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager#wipeDevice(int)
